# Eclipse Oxygen: How to add a button to toolbar for Navigate->Show in->Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse

I want to add the operation I found in the following path: Navigate -> Show In -> Project Explorer.

I understood that the way to do it in Eclipse is to go to window -> perspective -> customize perspective

But when I do it, this is what I see:
[image]

I can't see the option 'Show In' -> 'Project Explorer'

Do you know what I can do to add this button to the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

What you show is enough to add all possible Show In values to the 'Navigate > Show In' menu.

I don't think it is possible to add any of the Show In values to the tool bar.

Show In is also shown in the right click menu by most editors.